# Using a ZTE ZXHN H298A as a switch

Tags: router, switch

I have a ZTE gateway and I'm wondering if there is a way to use it as a switch. [This](https://www.xplore.ca/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/ENGLISH-Home-Phone-Manual-Nov-2018-web.pdf) is the user guide that is available when logging into the control panel. If it is not possible that is fine, I'm just not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: The 4 yellow ports are LAN1 to LAN4.  This can be used as a 4 port switch. Probably better to get a proper 8 port or 16 port switch.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, yes you can.  I often do it myself with modems, when I am stuck.

- You do need to make sure that the DHCP is turned off on it.  Otherwise, it will interfere with your network.  If you can not turn it off, then don't use it.
- Do not use the WAN port, only the 4 yellow ones should be used.

Try and see if it does the job for you.  A built-for-purpose switch is always going to be better though.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is answered in general, here are screenshots for

```
Device: ZXHN H298A V1.0
Software: TTN.21T1_220614
```

### Enable Bridge Mode

- Login to router management page.
- Locate `Easy Menu` at top bar.
- Locate `Bridge Mode` on left pane.
- Locate `Bridge Mode` drop-down in page body.
- Select `Bridge Mode: On` radio button.
- Click `Apply` button.

Note that `LAN4` is specified as bridge port

[image]

#### Disable DHCP Server

- Login to router management page.
- Locate `Local Network` at top bar.
- Locate `LAN` on left pane.
- Local `DHCP Provider` drop-down in page body.
- Select `DHCP Server: Off` radio button.
- Click `Apply` button.

[image]

---

**Trivia:** For anyone interested, ZTE routers can be jailbroken with [github.com/mkst/zte-config-utility](https://github.com/mkst/zte-config-utility)